# Youtube Live Stream Chat Messages

Tags: api, youtube, chat, live

I have been looking into getting messages from my live stream on youtube. I have a need to be able to process the chat in real time howver I have come to find a few issues.

For starter and the main issue really is that the order in which the chat comes through seems to be oldest first. This is rather a problem as if I am trying to handle new chat messages in real time, as the stream goes on the new messages go further and further down the list.

I must get next page keys which is a nightmare are the smallest page size i can requst from the api is 200 messages.

Its making the load a lot more that it needs to be.

Does anyone know how i might request the chat messages newest first or better handle the chat stream?

Im using PHP to read the API and I can read the messages into a database but i still have to go deeper and deeper as the chat goes on rather than just pull the new ones off the top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be saving the last `nextPageToken` response you get from calling the list endpoint. This way, you can call the endpoint with the `pageToken`, getting only the new messages from the last time you queried the API.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/list

Comment: Thank you very very much for pointing this out to me. It seems I didn't quite understand what the pageToken was for. This makes so much more sense now.  Have a great day man!

Comment: But what if my app dies and I loose the token and I just want the last page? Is it possible? And it must be .. because when I join a Live Stream the chat that loads up is the last page, instantly. YT doesn't start from the begging (especially on a 6 hour stream!)